# Why is it not recommended to use Javascript code in angularJS applications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I write an application that uses AngularJS, can I use other libraries like jQuery to add event listeners and change DOM elements?

Or is it not recommended to mix the two libraries because of angular's two way binding?

Edit: I know angular users jquery, but the logic of angular regarding the DOM is not exactly similar, that's what confused me.

Comment: it depends on what you're doing and how you mix them. you need to use js to code the app logic, but you should stay away from manipulating the view part of the DOM. the main problem is breaking the 2-way data binding by replacing massaged elements with plain jane ones.

Comment: [Angular uses jQuery](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-).

Comment: angularjs is itself a javascript, what the heck is this info?

Comment: @dandavis yes that's what I wanted to know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is written in Javascript. Any regular javascript you write is fine / encouraged. Angular also has a variation of jquery built in called JQLite, do some searching on that if you want to use it. You can also just include full on jquery but that IS discouraged because it is overkill.

Comment: a wide swath of regular javascript is not fine; ignoring DI, relying on closures/globals, manipulating the dom directly, minifying a DI function without an argument array, etc...

Comment: angular imposes restrictions that need not be adhered to by "Any regular javascript", which i feel is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you got this information but AngularJS uses jQLite which is a subset of jQuery. In the [FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-), they mention how you can go about using the jQuery library.

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being > bootstrapped.
>   If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to
>   its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

Reasons you may not want to use other libraries in conjunction with a library is really if you don't want to have extra dependencies but as long as you are using a library effectively among your team and within your application, I see no reason why this should be the case.

Comment: @dandavis which his quote clearly states.

Comment: @ShanRobertson: i ws refering to the first part that claims "AngularJS uses jQuery"

Comment: @dandavis My mistake. To be fair, their FAQ has the question "Does Angular use the jQuery library?" and they start their answer with **Yes** which is why I may have slipped up :P. You are right tho and I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like someone told you don't use any other libraries when you use Angular.js, because of potential conflicts between libraries. If so, then they were wrong - developers usually use other libraries with Angular, although when picking a set of libraries to use together, see how people have used them in the past.

Comment: i've heard the advice to go "all in" a lot from the community. it means picking plugins from a smaller "app store", at least for now